# Merging two identical files (same headers different info)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

First of all, sorry if this question was already asked, I looked up some of the answers and they were either really old or didn't help me.

I have 2 .csv files which have the same 'headers', something like this

[image: 1]

```
categoriaProducto         codigoEspecifico codigoGenerico img0Producto
Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry B072L7PVNQ       86K5PBAH       -
Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry B01D9FKME6       86K5PBAH       -
Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry B077Z5ST3P       86K5PBAH       -
Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry B00KLMFUKC       86K5PBAH       -
```

[image: 2]

```
categoriaProducto         codigoEspecifico codigoGenerico img0Producto
-                         B072L7PVNQ       -              someURL
-                         B01D9FKME6       -              someURL
-                         B077Z5ST3P       -              someURL
-                         B00KLMFUKC       -              someURL
```

So, they have in common the 'keys' urlProducto and codigoEspecificoProducto but in one file some data is missing, same with the other.

Is it there a way with pandas (or another library) to merge this files so I can get a new one with all the data.

EDIT: Images were too small for a human eye to see, sorry!
EDIT2: Added some of the text from the tables

Comment: Please provide information as _text_ so it can be copy-pasted into a terminal.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: Your screenshots of data are virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: On one sheet use vlookup() to fill in the blanks from the info on the other sheet with the ID, then do the reverse to complete the second sheet fully...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I was not clear with what I wanted on the question, I posted another question to the site with a more pandas focused approach, going to leave it here if someone runs into the same issue.

[Merging rows from two files if they have the same column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478998/merging-rows-from-two-files-if-they-have-the-same-column-value/54479436?noredirect=1#comment95766328_54479436)