# Merging rows from two files if they have the same column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently I'm scraping amazon's site for some data. The problem I encountered is that I couldn't really get all the data of a product from the same page.

What I ended up having was 2 files that have the same column headers but different data in the column itself. I pretty much never used pandas before apart from small things so my knowledge in the area is not that great.

For example, in one .csv file the product has 'code' 'name' 'url' 'size' with information but in the other it has 'code' 'price' 'image1' 'image2' and so on.

What is the best way to, if a code from file2 is the same as a code from file1, paste the data from file2 to file1 (or just make a new file). I will probably be working with tens of thousands of different product codes so the more efficient way possible the better.

I'll link two files as an example below

File 1: https://ufile.io/oojru

File 2: https://ufile.io/cytmq

Ill write as text some of the data above (didnt use all the headers because it would not look that good)

File 1

```
categoriaProducto codigoEspecifico codigoGenerico nombreProducto precioProducto

-                 B072L7PVNQ       -              -              price1
-                 B01D9FKME6       -              -              price2
-                 B077Z5ST3P       -              -              price3
-                 B00KLMFUKC       -              -              price4
```

File 2

```
 categoriaProducto codigoEspecifico codigoGenerico nombreProducto precioProducto

Clothing          B072L7PVNQ       86K5PBAH       name1              -
Clothing          B01D9FKME6       86K5PBAH       name2              -
Clothing          B077Z5ST3P       86K5PBAH       name3              -
Clothing          B00KLMFUKC       86K5PBAH       name4              -
```

In the case of the uploaded files and the text, the codes are in the same order. It is worth noting that this might not be the case.

I'd also like to add that, if a product code appears in file1, the code will be also in file2, but not the other way around.

I tried creating a new column from the file1 data and pasting that column in the file2 dataFrame, then saving the file. But then I found out that the codes might not be in order so that way did not work.

EDIT: I wasn't very clear on what I wanted, my apologies. The result I'm trying to get is something like this

```
 categoriaProducto codigoEspecifico codigoGenerico nombreProducto precioProducto

Clothing          B072L7PVNQ       86K5PBAH       name1          price1
Clothing          B01D9FKME6       86K5PBAH       name2          price2
Clothing          B077Z5ST3P       86K5PBAH       name3          price3
Clothing          B00KLMFUKC       86K5PBAH       name4          price4
```

Comment: Try Using :  `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ColumnName')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove only `NaN`s rows with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df1= pd.read_csv('example1.csv')
df2= pd.read_csv('example2.csv')

df1 = df1.set_index('codigoEspecificoProducto').dropna(how='all')
df2 = df2.set_index('codigoEspecificoProducto').dropna(how='all')
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Comment: That kind of worked but the result was weird. I got headers with _1 with the file 1 data next to headers with _2 with the file 2 data.  What i wanted is to, if the productCode is the same basically paste the data from file 2 to file 1 or the other way around

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help!. So what you did was combine the two dataframes with the product code as an index?

Comment: @Manuel - Exactly, need create index from `codigoEspecificoProducto` column for matching both DataFrames correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would place both files into a pandas dataframe and then use the dropduplicates method. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

You can specify the columns that you want to find duplicates of. By default, all columns must match to flag a duplicate. But this is configurable.

Then you can save it  to a single csv file

Comment: Edited the post to make what I wanted more clear, my plan is to merge the rows into one that has all the data, isnt this method going to delete rows if they have the same code?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought that you wanted to drop one of the rows.